# Off center forces on Chipmunk2D body

Tags: physics, chipmunk

I am puzzled by the behaviour I am seeing in my game that uses [Chipmunk2D](https://chipmunk-physics.net/) for physics.
I am not sure what I see is physically correct or not?

If I apply two forces as such, the tank turns, as expected.

[image: turning]

The force at RHS of tank is much larger, causing the turn.

So far so good.

However, if the differential gets just a little smaller, as shown below,
the tank goes **dead**-straight.

[image: straight]

I emulate the friction by [following the example](https://github.com/lawrencelomax/Chipmunk-Physics/blob/master/Demo/Tank.c#L117) for Chipmunk2D.

The forces are applied using the cpBodyApplyForceAtLocalPoint() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what kept the tank from turning.
The angular friction is stopping the turning.
The delta in the force magnitudes is too small to overcome the [angular friction](https://github.com/lawrencelomax/Chipmunk-Physics/blob/53db21256972e2c456ed05841da16cfcab5ec773/Demo/Tank.c#L122).